# Return all possible sums of number array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I have gone over my code a million times and can't figure out the problem. I have made a code that will return all the possible sums of numbers within an array. It works fine when there are 3 numbers in the array but if I add another number to the array it replaces a few of what should be sums with NaN.
Ex:

> array = [4, 6, 3, 7] is returning:
>
> [ 20, 16, 10, 13, 9, 14, 11, 7, 17, NaN, 13 ]
> and NaN should be "10"

```
array = [4, 6, 3, 7];
newarray = [0];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newarray[0] += array[i];
}
x = 0;
y = 1;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newarray.push((newarray[0]-array[i])); 
    if (i !== 0) {
        y = y+array.length; 
    }
    x = i;
    while (x < array.length) {
        if (x != i) {
            newarray.push((newarray[y]-array[x]));
        }
        x++;
    }
}
console.log(newarray);`
```

The fact that I am getting NaN in some slots where numbers should be leads me to believe there is a problem with variable x in the while loop but my brain is being racked on where the issue actually is.
http://jsfiddle.net/nsjY6/

Answer (score 2):

newarray[y] here cause NaN

```
newarray.push((newarray[y - 1]-array[x]));
```

[ 20, 16, 14, 17, 13, 14, 10, 6, 17, 10, 13 ]

add my version

```js
var array = [4, 6, 3, 7];

var newarray = [];

for (i=0; i< Math.pow(2, array.length); i++) {

    var s = i.toString(2)
    var t = 0;
    for (c in s) t += s[c] * array[c];

    newarray.push(t);
}

console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: That actually changes the whole output to an incorrect output but that does give me something to look at and from there I may be able to figure out exactly what pattern I need to set in place of just y.

Comment: Its the same if you initialize y with 0 instead of 1.

Comment: You're response, while not correct, lead to me figuring out where the problem was. Thank you very much.